# I can´t send emails server with Postfix in Debian

Tags: debian, email, postfix

im trying to sent mail through php, in  a Debian server with postfix, when i run the following script in the server, the code tells me that the email was sent successfully, This is my code:

```
<?php
 $to = "themailtest@gmail.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Email successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Email delivery failed¦</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

But, when I check the mail of the recipient,  is not in the inbox the mail that was sent. What files should I change in the configuration of postfix?

I post some of my configuration file of postfix:

- /etc/postfix/main.cf

  ```
  #See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
  #Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
  #line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
  #is /etc/mailname.
  #myorigin = /etc/mailname

  smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
  biff = no

  #appending .domain is the MUA's job.
  append_dot_mydomain = no

  #Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
  #delay_warning_time = 4h

  readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

  #TLS parameters
  smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
  smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
  smtpd_use_tls=yes
  smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
  smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

  #See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
  #information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

  myhostname = simbiosis_ucv
  alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
  alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
  mydestination = simbiosis_ucv, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
  relayhost = [gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com]:587
  mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
  mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
  mailbox_size_limit = 0
  recipient_delimiter = +
  inet_interfaces = all
  html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
  smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
  smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/passwd
  smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
  smtp_use_tls = yes
  smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
  ```
- /etc/hosts

  ```
  127.0.0.1    localhost
  190.169.94.56    tesisvergaraomana tesisvergaraomana

  The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
  ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  fe00::0 ip6-localnet
  ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
  ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
  ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
  ```
- /var/log/mail.log

  ```
   Apr  5 16:21:27 tesisvergaraomana postfix/smtp[10172]: 3427C22E015: to=    <javiervergara2004@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com[74.125.196.109]:587, delay=0.54, delays=0.1/0.01/0.37/0.07, dsn=5.7.0, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com[74.125.196.109] said: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. t9sm11828331yhg.18 - gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
   Apr  5 16:21:27 tesisvergaraomana postfix/cleanup[10157]: CD71422E016: message-id=<20140405205127.CD71422E016@simbiosis_ucv>
   Apr  5 16:21:27 tesisvergaraomana postfix/bounce[10173]: 3427C22E015: sender non-delivery notification: CD71422E016
   Apr  5 16:21:27 tesisvergaraomana postfix/qmgr[25492]: CD71422E016: from=<>, size=2403, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
   Apr  5 16:21:27 tesisvergaraomana postfix/qmgr[25492]: 3427C22E015: removed
   Apr  5 16:21:27 tesisvergaraomana postfix/local[10159]: CD71422E016: to=<root@simbiosis_ucv>, relay=local, delay=0.11, delays=0.05/0/0/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
   Apr  5 16:21:27 tesisvergaraomana postfix/qmgr[25492]: CD71422E016: removed
   Apr  5 16:39:01 tesisvergaraomana postfix/pickup[10185]: BB34622E016: uid=0 from=<root>
   Apr  5 16:39:01 tesisvergaraomana postfix/cleanup[10333]: BB34622E016: message-id=<20140405210901.BB34622E016@simbiosis_ucv>
   Apr  5 16:39:01 tesisvergaraomana postfix/qmgr[25492]: BB34622E016: from=<root@simbiosis_ucv>, size=785, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
   Apr  5 16:39:01 tesisvergaraomana postfix/local[10335]: BB34622E016: to=<root@simbiosis_ucv>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.2, delays=0.13/0/0/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
   Apr  5 16:39:01 tesisvergaraomana postfix/qmgr[25492]: BB34622E016: removed
   Apr  5 16:40:01 tesisvergaraomana postfix/pickup[10185]: D29A222E016: uid=104 from=<smmsp>
   Apr  5 16:40:01 tesisvergaraomana postfix/cleanup[10333]: D29A222E016: message-id=<20140405211001.D29A222E016@simbiosis_ucv>
   Apr  5 16:40:01 tesisvergaraomana postfix/qmgr[25492]: D29A222E016: from=<smmsp@simbiosis_ucv>, size=696, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
   Apr  5 16:40:01 tesisvergaraomana postfix/local[10335]: D29A222E016: to=<root@simbiosis_ucv>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.19, delays=0.13/0/0/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
   Apr  5 16:40:01 tesisvergaraomana postfix/qmgr[25492]: D29A222E016: removed
  ```
- /etc/resolv.conf

  ```
  nameserver 190.169.94.5
  ```
- postconf -n

  ```
  alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
  alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
  append_dot_mydomain = no
  biff = no
  config_directory = /etc/postfix
  html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
  inet_interfaces = all
  mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
  mailbox_size_limit = 0
  mydestination = simbiosis_ucv, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
  myhostname = simbiosis_ucv
  mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
  readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
  recipient_delimiter = +
  relayhost = [gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com]:587
  smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
  smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/passwd
  smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
  smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
  smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
  smtp_use_tls = yes
  smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
  smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
  smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
  smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
  smtpd_use_tls = yes
  ```

My goal is to get a full functionaly mail server, and it can send email to all address

```
    host: strix.ciens.ucv.ve
    port: 465
    domain: ciens.ucv.ve
    username: mail.test@ciens.ucv.ve
    active ssl
```

Can anyone point me to what to change in the configuration?. I need to install another tool?I hope that's all. If you need something else, let me know.

Comment: And the mail queue is empty.

Comment: What makes you think it's postfix that's the problem and not your php script? Have you checked your mail logs? What happens if you send an email using a command line tool such as `sendmail` instead of your script?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the log entry:

> Apr  5 16:21:27 tesisvergaraomana postfix/smtp[10172]: 3427C22E015: to=    , relay=gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com[74.125.196.109]:587, delay=0.54, delays=0.1/0.01/0.37/0.07, dsn=5.7.0, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com[74.125.196.109] said: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. t9sm11828331yhg.18 - gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command))

Apparently something is wrong with you tls configuration.

First of all, you should setup a "proper" certificate. How to do that for a self signed certificate, you can check here e.g.:
[create postfix certificate](http://www.e-rave.nl/create-a-self-signed-ssl-key-for-postfix)

Then you use configuration option:

> smtpd_use_tls = yes

If you look that up the documentation reveals the following:

> smtp_use_tls (default: no) Opportunistic mode: use TLS when a remote
>   SMTP server announces STARTTLS support, otherwise send the mail in the
>   clear. Beware: some SMTP servers offer STARTTLS even if it is not
>   configured. With Postfix < 2.3, if the TLS handshake fails, and no
>   other server is available, delivery is deferred and mail stays in the
>   queue. If this is a concern for you, use the smtp_tls_per_site feature
>   instead.
>
> This feature is available in Postfix 2.2
>
> and later. With Postfix 2.3 and later use smtp_tls_security_level
>   instead.

Documentation for `smtp_tls_security_level` you can look up here:
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_security_level

(I have to admit that I personally use  the  option `smtpd_use_tls = yes` with a self-signed-certificate without any troubles)

You can find more info here about postfix and tls here: 
http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html

Additionally it seems you are working with a relay host (`relayhost = [gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com]:587`). Which means that all mail you send is routed through the relay-host. In most cases the port 587 can only be accessed with a proper tls connection. Therfore you need a working tls setup and if you need to authenticate on the google relayhost, you have to set-up additional configuration-options.

Take a look here for that:
http://baldric.net/upstream-authentication-with-tls-on-postfix/

Furthermore you have also to verify that postfix has access to all the necessary files. I did not use Debian for quite a time, but afaik it runs or ran in a `chroot`ed environment in Debian. So make sure all necessary files are reachable for postfix (in your case basically the configuration files, certificates and caches).

I'll hope this points you in the right direction. Good luck. :)